# Python Calendar

Tags: python, calendar

Create a calendar program that allows the user to enter a day, month, and year in three separate variables as shown below.

```
Please enter a date

Day:

Month: 

Year:
```

Then, ask the user to select from a menu of choices using this formatting:
Menu:

```
1)   Calculate the number of days in the given month.

2)   Calculate the number of days left in the given year.
```

The program must include the following functions:
leap_year: Takes the year as a parameter and returns 1 if a year is a leap year
 (Links to an external site.)
 and 0 if it is not. This information will only be used by other functions.
number_of_days: This subprogram will accept two parameters in the following order: month and year. It will return how many days are in the given month
 (Links to an external site.)
.
daysunderscoreleft: This will accept three parameters in the following order: day, month, and year. It should calculate the number of days left in the year, and return the value of number of days left. This should not include the date the user entered in the count.

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(month, year):

    if month in ['September', 'April', 'June', 'November']:
        print("30")


    elif month in ['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August','October','December']:
        print("31")

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == True:
        print("29")

    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == False:
        print("28")

    else:
        return None

print("Please enter a date: ")
x = int(input("Day: "))
y = str(input("Month: "))

z = str(input("Year: "))

print("Menu:")
o = int(input("1)    Calculate the number of day in the given month. \n2)    Calculate the number of days left in the given year. "))


if(o == "2"):
    print (days_in_month(y,z))
```

This is what I have so far. I am kind of confused on how to find the number of days left in a month and year and I just need help with that. Sorry for the messy format, I didn't know how to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(day, month, year):
    if month in ['September', 'April', 'June', 'November']:
        return 30 - day
    elif month in ['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August','October','December']:
        return 31 - day
    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == True:
        return 29 - day
    elif month == 'February' and is_leap_year(year) == False:
        return 28 - day
    else:
        return None

print("Please enter a date: ")
x = int(input("Day: "))
y = str(input("Month: "))

z = int(input("Year: "))

print("Menu:")
o = int(input("1)    Calculate the number of day in the given month. \n2)    Calculate the number of days left in the given year.\n"))

if(o == 1):
    print (days_in_month(x, y,z))
```

It will give you the `days left in month`.

Output:

```
Please enter a date: 
Day: 15
Month: February
Year: 2020
Menu:
1)    Calculate the number of day in the given month. 
2)    Calculate the number of days left in the given year.
1
14
```

Will it be okay to find the days left in year using any python library, then i can do it..

Comment: Its okay, I think I have an idea on how to do the days left in a year. Thanks. I don't why my question got down voted. thanks for the help! But for the days left in a year, can't you do the same thing you did to find the days left in a month?

Comment: i guess that cannot be used, you need to iterate over the months to get the results